# Angular 5 - Passing data to another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this form which through an API service i can get data from a specific user so i want to send that data to another component and then extract it using *ngFor, but i really don't have any clue about how to do it.
(Also i must say it, the other component is not a child from the parent view)

Comment: You can create service to store data and use it in any component you want

Comment: u can share data using services or use redux to create a store for your app

Comment: please check https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    setData(message: string) {
        // just an example:
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In your parent component:

```
this.dataService.setData(something);
```

In your other component you can subscribe:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
    // do stuff with the data, for example:
    this.myData = data;
);
```

Don't forget the constructor in your components:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
```

---

An other solution could be to use Ngrx: https://github.com/ngrx/platform

Comment: I don't get it in this part: private subject = new Subject<any>();.  in new Subject what i should put, the name of the class of my component?

Comment: @Netox No. It is somekind of 'container' for your data. We're using it in Rxjs. You can put your class in the place of `any`, if you want. These links can help you, I think: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject In the first example, BehaviorSubject is a special type of Subject. You can read about Subject here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md